# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error in Ajax $post request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to create a chat box and performing this AJAX post in Codeigniter but for some reason I am getting a server 500 internal server error and no response at all when I use firebug? Can anyone help?

This is my Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a#submit").click(function(){

        var chat_message_content = $("input#chat").val();

        if(chat_message_content == ""){

            return false;
        }

        $.post(base_url + "index.php/abovetheblues/add_chat_messages", {
            chat_message_content : chat_message_content, 
            user_id : user_id
        }, 
        function(data){

            alert(data);
        },"json");


        return false;
    });
    return false;

});
```

This is my controller

```
function add_chat_messages() {
        // Grab the $chat_message_content, $user_id
        $user_id = $this->input->post($this->session->userdata("user_id"));
        $chat_message_content = $this->input->post('chat_message_content');

        $this->abt_db->add_chat_message($user_id, $chat_message_content);
    }
```

This is my model

```
function add_chat_message($user_id, $chat_message_content) {

    $query_str = "INSERT INTO chat_message(user_id, chat_message_content) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($query_str, array($user_id, $chat_message_content));
}
```

And my view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var user_id = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata("user_id"); ?>";



</script>

<!--loads the header-->
<?php $this->load->view('abt-header'); ?>
<!--this is the login page-->

<div data-role="page" id="Abt-chat" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Peer Chat</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <div id="chat_viewport"></div>

            <p>
                <label>Input Chat: </label>
                <input name="chat" id="chat" type="text" value=""/>

            </p>

            <p>
                <?php echo anchor('#', 'Send Chat', array('title' => 'Send Chat', 'id' => 'submit')); ?>
            </p>  

        </div> 
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Need your PHP code. If its a 500 error its a problem with your php script.

Comment: manually open your php page in browser with request parameters to get the error message.

Comment: if you get a 500 error, then check your server's error log. what you see in a browser is deliberately VERY vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing user id as user_id. But while retrieving it in function you are doing mistake. Change it like below.

```
$user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
```

And also -> need to be there before query()

```
$this->db->query($query_str, array($user_id, $chat_message_content));
```